# JavaScript: Global Objects Or Function Return Local?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

When writing sound code should i be using global objects or passing locals to functions and then returning the functions local object back to the original function?

```
function func1(obj) {
  ..modify obj
  return obj;
}

object = func1(object)
..do something with modified object
```

or

```
var object={..};

function func1() {
  ..modifiy object
}

function func2() {
    func1();
    ..do something with modified object
}

func2();
```

the first seems more readable, the second seems like better practice...

Comment: The first seems like better practice, the second will suffer from side effects. I would create a constructor and set the object as property then add the methods to the prototype.

Comment: The first IS better practice, not just seems like it. There are situations where a global is needed (like the global JQuery object or it's alias $) but it's rare and should be very limited.

Comment: This question is very broad and the answer depends on a multitude of circumstances. Stick a closure around both of those examples and voila, no global, but then which one is better practice? Depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript best practice is to not use global variables unless you absolutely have to. That being said it really depends on your situation. Douglas Crockford has 2 really nice articles on this subject. The first explains why they are so bad, the second provides tips for when a global variable must be used,

1. http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/
2. http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/04/16/global-domination-part-two/

Comment: It's best practice in most languages, not just Javascript.

Comment: @Barmar I am not very familiar with many other languages most of my experience is in JS, thank you for letting me know though :)